# Multiple rows into a multiple columns

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a problem, displaying data in columns.

I have EX: emptable

```
emp id
--------    
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9
 10
```

I want this change in multiple different columns, in select query or in stored procedure any way

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Please help in how solve this problem

Thanks
Raja

Answer (score 3):

In SQL 2005 you should be able to use the [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16) function.

Example: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20191230182030/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/lorint/archive/2006/08/04/87166.aspx)